# image broken in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem on displaying my uploaded image in php codeigniter:

After uploading the images to the database, several images become broken when I try to display them on the website. What am I doing wrong?

this my controller

```
public function prosesupload(){

            $config['upload_path']          = './gambar/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|docx';
            $config['max_size']             = 10000;
            $config['max_width']            = 5000;
            $config['max_height']           = 5000;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                   echo 'fail to upload';
            }
            else
            {
                $img = $this->upload->data();
                $gambar = $img['file_name'];




                $data = array(


                'certificates_img' => $gambar,

                );
            $this->db->insert('certificate', $data);
            redirect('certificate/index');
            }

    }
```

this my model

```
var $table="certificate";

public function getCertificate($table)

    {
    $data = $this->db->get($table);
    return $data->result_array();
    }
```

this is my view

```
<div class="content" >
<br>
<center>
<table>
            <?php
            foreach($certificate as $key){
            ?>
            <tr>
            <div class="box"  id="" style=";">
                <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('/gambar/'.$key-
              >certificates_img) ?> " width="80%" height="800px" ><br><br>
                </td>

            </div>

            <?php } ?></tr>
        </table>
        <p align="center"><?php echo $links; ?>
 </center>
```

Comment: are you saving blob to database  or image file to any directory?

Comment: just check if its in the correct path

Comment: You use `result_array()` to retrieve the result and in your view call to a property `$key->certificates_img`, use `$key['certificates_img']`

Comment: The problem is due to the file name you are saving to database and directory. 
assign the filename to configuration too so that your database file name match with the file in the directory.
$config['file_name'] = $filename;

Comment: Have you set the base url in the config.php you need to

Comment: Abid Nawaz, i saves image in both database and file directory

Comment: Abid Nawaz, can you explain more to me how to assign the filename because i don't really understand

Comment: wolfgang1983, yes, i've set the base url in config php

Comment: Ghost, the upload path is successfully stored in database and file upload folder but certain images cannot be displayed (image broken)

Comment: @FaizatulNajihah by broken do you mean the image uploads and is corrupted, or that the image doesn't appear because the link is incorrect? have you looked/tried my answer?

Comment: @AbidNawaz no, if anything hes doing it right because CI uses the name of the file for the upload, thus by getting the filename from the upload data it will be correct

Comment: @Alex, yes, the image uploads and is corrupted, the link i think is correct. i've tried your answer but the result same...the images cannot been viewed but stored in database and folder upload.

Comment: can you do 4 things (1) post a picture of the database with the image (2) verify that the image exists in `htdocs/gambar/` (3) post the rest of your controller specifically the function where you load your view! (4) verify that your `base_url` is set and properly configured

Comment: @Alex,....(1) this is my database with image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLnLa.png
(2)this is my folder upload for my images
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nsRU.png
(3)this is my controller that specifically for view the image

    public function certificateV(){
   $this->data['certificate'] = $this->db->get('certificate')->result_array();
   $this->load->view('certificateView',$this->data);
   
  }

(4) my base_url 

    <img src="<?php echo base_url('/gambar/' . $key['certificates_img']); ?> " width="80%" height="800px" ><br><br></td>
 image with id 7 cannot be displayed.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I'm not sure it will fix anything (check controller function for view). But... can you echo your `<?php echo base_url('/gambar/'); ?>` and post here? I see your folder structure is `htdocs/ARES/gambar` and if your base_url isn't set to `http://localhost/ARES/` then of course you will have an issue.

Comment: Also you will have issues down the line displaying the returned rows as you are allowing .pdf and .docx and those obviously won't display in an image wrapper.

Comment: @Alex, my problem had been solved. i recreate the table in the database and the image can be displayed properly. Tq Alex for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an `result_array()` using `getCertificate()` thus you can access its values via `$key['certificates_img']` if you wanted to access them as an object as you are doing now you'd have to return `result()`.

Using your method you can do this:

Controller method for view:

```
function certificateV()
{
    $data['certificate'] = $this->db->get('certificate')->result_array();
    $this->load->view('certificateView', $data);
}
```

certificateView:

```
<div class="content">
    <br>
    <center>
        <table>
            <?php
            foreach ($certificate as $key) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <div class="box"  id="" style=";">
                        <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('/gambar/' . $key['certificates_img']); ?> " width="80%" height="800px" ><br><br></td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
        <p align="center"><?php echo $links; ?>
    </center>
```

Note: cleaned up your code a bit, your ending loop `</tr>` was outside the close of the foreach.